# Stream training videos to remote offices

Tags: linux, apache, amazon-web-services, streaming, video-streaming

So I lead a team of engineers located across 3 timezones, and when we have a meeting we record it, so that it can reviewed at a later date. Currently we are just storing it on an apache server. If someone wants to watch one of the videos they must download it and then watch it.

Would it be possible to configure it so that they could stream the videos instead of downloading them?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the video is mp4, and if you have reasonable bandwidth available, then you can simply make the video available on your server and use the HTML5 video tag on a web page to stream it.

If you don't have or don't want a separate web page just for this, then you can use a general purpose video player, such as VLC http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html, and simply provide the URL to the video on your server.

One thing to be aware of - a regular MP4 file has the metadata at the end of the file, but for streaming you want this to be moved to the start of the file. There are several tools which will do this (google mp4 fast start) - here is an example:

- https://github.com/danielgtaylor/qtfaststart